# Codeigniter post method conflicts with pagination

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a codeigniter search form which includes a dropdown list (Car) and a checkbox array (Car types). I am using POST method to get values from database but post method conflicts with pagination. Could you please check my code and help me to find the mistake.

Here is my controller

```
   public function search($offset = 0) {
                $limit = 3;

                $this->load->library('form_validation');
                $this->load->model('model_x');

                $this->form_validation->set_rules('car', 'Car','required');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('types', 'Car Type','required');

               if($this->form_validation->run()) {

        $car= $this->input->post('car');
        $types = $this->input->post('types'); 

        $this->load->library('pagination');

        $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/abc/cont/search/'; 

        // 'http://localhost/abc' is my base url

        $config['total_rows'] = 14;
        $config['per_page'] = 3; 

        $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->initialize($config);

                if ($this->model_x->did_search($car, $types, $limit, $offset)){

                $data["results"] = $this->model_x->did_search($car, $types, $limit, $offset); 
                $this->load->view("search_ok",$data);           
                }          
                }
                else
                {
                $data['message'] = 'Please select your options.';   

                $this->load->view("search_nok",$data);          
                 }              
           }
```

Comment: "Perhaps I should insert the posted values in the URL" - yeap, although obviously it would cease to be POST and would become GET instead, or you could store the POST vars in `$this->session->userdata` so it's read from the session each time.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I have just tried to save the variables in the session but it did not work. Could you please check my edited question.

Comment: can you please share your view code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `get` parameters for search would be better since besides making pagination easier, it will allow users to access that link directly through Bookmarks or other hyperlinks without needing to go through posting your form every time they need to repeat a "saved" search.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  pagination with post method search data php ci
store post data in session and on second page check session with 2?page_rows=5
get from URL.

This will work

```
if (session_id() && !empty($this->input->get('page_rows', 0))) { 
    $pData= $this->session->userdata('custumer_data');
    .... 
    then query
}
```